# In android/build.gradle file in flutter app, the Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':jitsi_meet' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

this is the error i m getting but my kotlin version is 1.7.10
even after i change my version to 1.9.22 which is latest, it still shows the same error.

I tried changing my kotlin version but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you include your pubspec file?